# How to change the color of the prefix "b", "r", "f" or "u" before strings?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-python

Is there any way to do this ? I'm using vim 8.2 with this python [plugin](https://github.com/vim-python/python-syntax).
The inside of f strings for example is correctly highlighted but not the "f"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax highlighting is a relatively deep subject and extending an existing highlighting scheme may get complicated depending on certain factors. I recommend you find a good reference and read up on things. One highly regarded source of information  is [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) which has three chapters (45-47) devoted to the topic

With that being said, I suspect this particular case can be handled fairly easily since a standalone "f", "b", "r" or "u" is pretty unique (i.e. unlikely to occur elsewhere in Python source code).

Here's a "quick and dirty" solution that works for me...

First, since you are just supplementing the existing configuration, create an "after" file to contain the new config: `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`. Edit this file and add these two lines...

```
syntax match pythonStrFormatTag /\<[brfu]\>/
highlight link pythonStrFormatTag Special
```

The first line defines a regex pattern to match the letters of interest. The surrounding `\<` and `\>` prevent a match when those letters are part of a word. If you want to use a slightly more refined pattern you could try `\<[brfu]\>\ze['"]` which will require a single or double quote after the letter but, thanks to the `\ze`, will not include it in the text to color.

Replace `Special` with any existing highlight group that has a color scheme that you like. Run `:hi` while editing a Python file to see what's available.

That's it. I just did a quick sanity test and it works but let me know if there are any issues. (The pattern might need a bit of refinement if there's a conflicting match that I didn't consider.)

Comment: I would use a lookahead to avoid consuming the quote, and then use `['"]` because python, but otherwise looks great

Comment: `\zs` and `\ze` actually don’t play well in syntax (or at least they didnt; maybe thats changed). They consume the parts of the match and discard them, so other syntax never has a chance to match those pieces. The perl-style operators (odd syntax, hard to remember for me) don’t consume (or do and put it back, same difference?), so they don’t interfere that way

Comment: `grep 'syn match.*\\z[se]' /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/*.vim` returns over 500 matches...so I feel better about it now. :)

Comment: Interesting. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49323753/4400820, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58152552/4400820, https://stackoverflow.com/q/53727694/4400820

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks for the detailed explanations and the link, I will look into it :)

Comment: @BLayer In fact, it does conflict with something. Now, the pattern inside my formatted string (f-string) is wrongly highlighted. See before and after: https://imgur.com/a/QZQdfrB

Comment: Two things. 1) I can't reproduce that but I'm not using the plugin...just the native Vim syntax file. I'll have to download it. 2) Does using the second pattern I mentioned,  `\<[brfu]\>\ze"`, change things? (Or if that's what you're using try the first pattern.)

Comment: You could also try the pattern that DBK and I have been discussing: `\<[brfu]\>"\@=`. (Note that when I reference a pattern I'm not including the `/` delimiter on either side. Don't leave those off.)

Comment: @BLayer In fact I use the [vim-polyglot](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot) plugin (which does load the python plugin I originally mentionned, I don't think it can be an issue). So, when using f-string, the text inside the "{}" braces are interpreted as python code, thus I can achive this highlighting. But with your pattern (tested all of them), the text inside those braces are wrongly highlighted (not interpreted as python code): https://imgur.com/a/kZR9vYG
Also, I use this theme: https://github.com/NicoAdrian/vim-monokai-pro

Comment: @NicoAdrian I installed the plugin mentioned in your question (python-syntax) and it is not doing that extra syntax highlighting in f-strings. Which suggests some other part of vim-polyglot is doing it or there's some unmentioned configuration at play. As it stands now, with the information I have, I don't believe your question can be answered any more completely than I've done.

Comment: @BLayer I just installed `python-vim` only and not `vim-polyglot` and I can confirm what you said, it does some additional configurations because I can't reproduce the output of my screenshots from my previous responses. They probably do this here https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot/blob/master/syntax/python.vim ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129960/discussion-between-b-layer-and-nicoadrian).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble (just read those links) Yes, interesting. What you said is true (as is what I guessed about relative performance)...or _was_ true. My brief investigation suggests "was" but my confidence in that is low now. I'll have to look closer...if I can only find the time. :P